# How to store field Id in a row?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, ajax

I write a web site with jquery and lot of ajax request to get data for table and ask data modifications with PHP/MySql on server side.

Currently, I use id attribute to store the id of the field of the table (which is an autoincrement int value).
**And it works fine.**

BUT I have recently learned that id should be unique (and start with a letter...).
AND I have different tables that could have the same id value (for different sql table)
Then **I am not html (nor xhtml) compliant**...

How could I correct my code ?

- By using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function of jQuery ?
- An hidden html element with the id as value (`<span class="id">3</span>`) ?
- Other solution ?

---

Additional informations:
I have wrote a widget to manage my tables.
To add a new row, I do:

```
    row = $('<div class="row" id="'+item.id+'"/>');
    [...] // I add fields to my row
    row.appendTo(tableData);// tableData is the html element where rows are
```

When a field element is changed, I trigger an event to the table that will ask the modification to the server with the right id:

```
$(e.target).closest(".row").attr("id")
```

Comment: I think it would help to provide some "wrong" html code.

Comment: Ok, I have add some informations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are able to use [jQuery 1.4.3](http://api.jquery.com/data/) or greater look at using the html 5 `data-*` attributes.  jQuery 1.4.3 will automatically use those data- attributes and place them in the `.data()` collection on the element.

Example:

```
<table>
  <tr data-rowId="1">

  </tr>
</table>
```

`$("tr:first").data("rowId")` would print `1`

This method would also allow you to store json objects as well.

```
<table>
  <tr data-row='{"Id" : 1, "Name": "Smith"}'>

  </tr>
</table>
```

And than in your `data()`
`var row = $("tr:first").data("row")`
You can reference `row.Id` and `row.Name`

Comment: Looks great ! Is it compatible with IE ? (IE6?). Don't like IE, but it is requested...

Comment: Yep, it is just part of jQuery, I used it quite a bit for projects and works great in IE6 and all other major browsers.

Comment: +1 Great answer, but I think it's important to note that this is html5 and not xhtml compliant.

Comment: Ok, I will use this solution... I will also store other data that are sometimes stored in hidden span elements ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You can prefix your id with the table name :

```
<div id="mytable_1234"></div>
```

It's easy to extract the table name and the id from the field and this is HTML compliant.

```
var values = $(element).attr('id').split('_');
// values[0] is the table name and values[1] is the id.
```

You can use any other separator if you're already using underscores in your table names.

Comment: I think he might mean record (row) id's, fyi

Comment: @Jakub I put my example in a `div` element, but I think the OP will understand he can use this in a `tr` or anything else ;) And the pasted code in the question use a div too, So I wasn't that wrong...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I will use the .data(). In my opinion, it seems more clean.

Comment: @Benoît The data() answer is a great solution, but since I can't use HTML5 I have to stick to my solution... But I also think it's way more powerful to use HTML5 data fields..

Comment: Why HTML5 can't be used everywhere ?  (could it be a limitation for my web site ?)

Comment: It's only some silly limitation decided by the people upstairs ;) The only reason I can see to avoid HTML5 is the need of having something XML compliant, but this won't be relevant 90% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use [jQuery metadata](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata) .....

Its awesome to store data in html

Comment: Seems that standard jQuery function answer to my problem, I prefer not using external plugin.

Comment: personal choice .. i also like this way to store data in the HTML <table>
  <tr data-row='{"Id" : 1, "Name": "Smith"}'>

  </tr>
</table>

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `id` use `data-id` and use the `.data('id')` (*on that element*) to retrieve it with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I think... I understand your question - multiple data tables, all with autoincrement ids?

My solution would be pre-appending the ID with a letter (like you said) to differentiate it.

Example would be a dataset for 'cars' I would do:

```
<table>
<tr id="cars_1">
...
</tr>
<tr id="cars_2">
...
</tr>
<tr id="cars_3">
...
</tr>
</table>
```

Later if you have another table, bikes, you would do:

```
<table>
<tr id="bike_1">
...
</tr>
<tr id="bike_2">
...
</tr>
<tr id="bike_3">
...
</tr>
</table>
```

Your end result would be unique ID's while keeping the ID db value in mind, so you would do a simple check (if cars, then do this, etc), then to seperate the prefix (cars from the id 1, you would use something like the PHP `expolode()` fn).

Hope that clarifies it, and that I understood your question.